# How can I programmatically disable all menu item in my activity

Tags: android

In Android, I create my menu item like this?

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Menu1");
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Menu2");
        return true;
}
```

How can I set all the menu item disabled programmatically (in another part of the code in my activity, not in onCreateOptionsMenu() method itself)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`add` returns a `MenuItem` (which you can also retrieve from the `Menu` object), that you can store away into a variable.

```
MenuItem menu1;

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu1 = menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Menu1");
}

public void someOtherMethod() {
    if(menu1 != null) {
        // if it's null, options menu hasn't been created, so nevermind
        menu1.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems like the hard way to do things to me...  what if you've got a whole bunch of menu items?  Groups work a lot better for enabling/disabling items, plus you don't have to hold onto the MenuItem to do it.

Comment: i agree, i somehow managed to misread the post as being about a single items (although it said *all* in both title and body, hrrm). i +1'd you, yours is clearly the more efficient way

Answer (score 9):

You can use the groupId you set to disable/enable all the menu items at once, using `menu.setGroupEnabled()`.  So for example, since you added the items to group 0, you'd do:

```
menu.setGroupEnabled(0, false);
```

Also, if you want to dynamically modify the menu, you should hook into `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`.  `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is only called once per Activity, so it's good for setting up the initial menu structure, but `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` should be used to enable/disable menus as necessary later in the Activity.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to hide them completely if they should not be used (instead of disabling them).
For that I do:

```
menu.clear();
```

and to recreate it:

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

This also works for menu items added from fragments.

Answer (score 4):

If still relevant:

```
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    for(int i=0; i<menu.size(); i++){
        menu.getItem(i).setEnabled(isMenuEnabled);
    }
}
```

and call invalidateOptionsMenu() then isMenuEnabled changed

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple occasions where you want to do something with **all** items of a menu (for example changing the 'checked' state) there is an elegant solution using Kotlin Extension Properties:
(Building on top of the [answer of Valery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38890179/3504202))

In one place define the property 'items' of android.view.Menu:

```
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem

val Menu.items: List<MenuItem>
get() {
    val items = mutableListOf<MenuItem>()
    for (i in 0 until this.size()) {
        items.add(this.getItem(i))
    }
    return items
}
```

Now you can use it on any menu:

```
anyMenu.items.forEach { it.isEnabled = false }
```